# How can i adjust the height of katex superscript?

Tags: markdown, katex

I'm newbie to handling html, and I'm posting my studies in github blog.

My blog framework is hydejack, and the version is 6.4.0
I'm trying to use katex to represent some formula, but the katex superscript looks werid...
[image]
I tried to represet 750feet^2, but the shown image is the upper one as you can see.
Could somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code you wrote that generated that?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
$$(750feet^{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not intended behavior; for example, if you type the input `(750feet^{2})` into [the KaTeX demo page](https://katex.org), you get [image: KaTeX screenshot]

Notice how the fonts differ; here, the "feet" are italics. My guess would therefore be that you're not including the KaTeX CSS and thereby not getting the font definitions. Did you include a `<link rel="spreadsheet"...>` tag in your file, as in [this documentation](https://katex.org/docs/browser.html)? Can you confirm that it's loading?